# “De toute façon” vs. “de toute manière” vs. “en tout cas”

Tags: adverbes, locutions

From my understanding, they’re all ways of saying “in any case.” Are there nuanced differences in usage? Or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***En tout cas*** is leading ***de toute façon*** in usage while alternatives are trailing.

[image]

The meaning is often the same but there are a few cases where only ***en tout cas*** seems idiomatic, when it means ***although***/***at least***:

> Il habitait chez des amis, au début **en tout cas**.
>
> Il habitait chez des amis, au début <s>**de toute façon**</s>.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you can’t use ‘de toute façon’ here? Or is that just the way it is without explanation? I know there are tons of “just because” rules in French (as well as in English).

Comment: In this sentence, this is really related to "au début". Without it, you can use both. "au début en tout cas" really means "at last at the begining !". Similar to "...amis, au moins au début".

Comment: Yes. There is no problem with *De toute façon, au début, il habitait chez des amis*.

Answer (score 2):

*De toute façon* = *De toute manière*.
*De toute façon* is a bit familiar, but they are interchangeable.
They are equal to "anyway".

Comment: *De toute façon* n'est pas plus familier que *De toute manière*